# is there AN ERASER TOOL in INKSPACE vector graphics editor?

Tags: 14.04

I am new to ubuntu.I tried to use inkspace vector graphics editor for graphic designing but could not find any eraser tool.Please help

Comment: Do you want that as an artistic effect on vector objects, or do you want to remove those objects or their nodes with it?

Comment: http://goinkscape.com/how-to-erase-in-inkscape/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Inkscape for a while and I've never come across an eraser tool. It's vector, GIMP on the other hand is good for general purpose photo editing and yes it has an eraser tool. `apt-get install gimp` to play around with it. You may need to read on the net before you become acquainted with gimp it has a high learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [eraser tool in Inkscape](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Eraser.html), but due to the nature of vector graphics (which is very different from raster/bitmap graphics), it behaves not at all like the eraser tool in bitmap/raster editors like Gimp. Once you'll get more familiar with vector drawing, you will see that "classic" erasing doesn't make that much sense in vector graphics.